# Draw random design on uiview

Tags: iphone, facebook

I want to draw a random design on uiview just like we are drawing on paint brush I want where user touch on screen start drawing. like if he wants to write ok in it than he can draw it.if he want to make duck or ball so he can make it. plz help me.

Comment: Possible to duplicate of above question. Refer the link.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3128752/draw-line-in-uiview

Comment: No my question is different draw any design on view

Comment: This can be the best one for starting purpose. http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/ipad-development/draw-circle-triangle-and-rectangle-in-iphone/

Comment: No in this there is fix design but I want to design like bat or any other design

Comment: I want like a paint brush as user touch screen it starts to draw on view

Comment: may I recieve ur reply it's urgent

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
In this, You will have to use `self.view.frame` wherever i have `myPic.Frame`.

In Header File:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface DrawView : UIView {

    UIImage *myPic;

    NSMutableArray *myDrawing;

}

-(void)drawPic:(UIImage *)thisPic;

-(void)cancelDrawing;

@end
```

and in Implementation File:

```
#import "DrawView.h"

@implementation DrawView

-(void)drawPic:(UIImage *)thisPic {

    myPic = thisPic;

    [myPic retain];

    [self setNeedsDisplay];

}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    float newHeight;

    float newWidth;

    if (!myDrawing) {

        myDrawing = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];

    }

    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    if (myPic != NULL) {

        float ratio = myPic.size.height/460;

        if (myPic.size.width/320 > ratio) {

            ratio = myPic.size.width/320;

        }

        newHeight = myPic.size.height/ratio;

        newWidth = myPic.size.width/ratio;

        [myPic drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newWidth,newHeight)];

    }

    if ([myDrawing count] > 0) {

        CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 5);

        for (int i = 0 ; i < [myDrawing count] ; i++) {

            NSArray *thisArray = [myDrawing objectAtIndex:i];

            if ([thisArray count] > 2) {

                float thisX = [[thisArray objectAtIndex:0] floatValue];

                float thisY = [[thisArray objectAtIndex:1] floatValue];

                CGContextBeginPath(ctx);

                CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, thisX, thisY);

                for (int j = 2; j < [thisArray count] ; j+=2) {

                    thisX = [[thisArray objectAtIndex:j] floatValue];

                    thisY = [[thisArray objectAtIndex:j+1] floatValue];

                    CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, thisX,thisY);

                }

                CGContextStrokePath(ctx);

            }

        }

    }

}

- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    [myDrawing addObject:[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:4]];

    CGPoint curPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];

    [[myDrawing lastObject] addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:curPoint.x]];

    [[myDrawing lastObject] addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:curPoint.y]];

}

- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    CGPoint curPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];

    [[myDrawing lastObject] addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:curPoint.x]];

    [[myDrawing lastObject] addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:curPoint.y]];

    [self setNeedsDisplay];

}

- (void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    CGPoint curPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];

    [[myDrawing lastObject] addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:curPoint.x]];

    [[myDrawing lastObject] addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:curPoint.y]];

    [self setNeedsDisplay];

}

-(void)cancelDrawing {

    [myDrawing removeAllObjects];

    [self setNeedsDisplay];

}

- (void)dealloc {

    [super dealloc];

    [myPic release];

    [myDrawing release];

}

@end
```

Comment: Thank u for givemetime but Nothing is display on simulator

Answer (score 0):

you will have to make your UIView a subClass of the above. And in your controller class.m file, you'll have to add and call these two methods.
I hope this works.

-(IBAction)clear {

```
[self.view cancelDrawing];
```

}

-(IBAction)saveDrawing 
{

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);

[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

UIImage *finishedPic = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(finishedPic, self, @selector(exitProg:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
```

}