# I want to draw grid with following path & user can fill that as shown in image in ios

Tags: objective-c, uiview

I want to draw grid like in first image for all devices & user is allowed to fill path only by dragging on grid as a second image,I have tried lots of stuff but no use of it,please suggest me how should i make?

[image: First image to draw a grid & second image shows to fill path]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Key Idea**

1. First, you need to override `UIView`, so that you got to draw on something.
2. Second you need to know the `height` & `width` prior drawing the whole board.
3. Third need to maintain a data structure which will keep track where to draw & where not to.

First point is easy, we need to override the `UIView` class. We will do most of our task in `drawRect` method. For the example purpose say the extended class name is `CustomGridView`.

Before discussing point #2 we will discuss #3.

Each grid can be in one of the three states,

- empty (no box drawn around this grid)
- surrounded (box drawn around this grid)
- filled surrounded (box drawn & filled with blue color)

so we will declare an `enum` for this three states

```
typedef enum{
    EMPTY_BLOCK = 0,
    SURROUNDED_BLOCK,
    FILLED_SURROUNDED_BLOCK
}
```

Now we will keep track of the grid using a 2 dimensional array of numbers as declared follows:

```
 NSMutableArray<NSMutableArray<NSNumber*>*>* gridStructure;
```

initialise the array with `EMPTY_BLOCK` & `SURROUNDED_BLOCK` as it is wanted in the grid to be shown. For example say you want a grid of height 5 block & width 4 block. All of the outer block will be `SURROUNDED_BLOCK`, then the array should look like this.

> 1, 1, 1, 1
>
> 1, 0, 0, 1
>
> 1, 0, 0, 1
>
> 1, 0, 0, 1
>
> 1, 1, 1, 1

now when ever a user will touch the grid, fill that grid position with `FILLED_SURROUNDED_BLOCK`.

Now the most point #2, most tedious thing. in the `drawRect` you will be specified with the `rect` which will denote the `height` & `width` of the `CustomGridView`. Here you will draw the grids according to the array co-ordinates. You have to split up the entire view into `grid_width`*`grid_height` spaces. Then according to the 2 dimensional array's value you will do the drawing. For example

if you found `EMPTY_BLOCK` then draw nothing and rest of them as follows.

Additional resources:

1. Add a `UIPangestureRecognizer` to track the user touch path & track the position in the 2 dimensional grid array. After updating the 2 dimensional array grid update the view's `drawRect` call `[self setNeedsDisplay]`.
2. Draw 4 line two represent the `FILLED_SURROUNDED_BLOCK` thing.
3. How to draw a line is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3128752/draw-line-in-uiview/5391559#5391559)

Best of luck.

Upon the above idea, here is a sample implementation

**GridView.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

IB_DESIGNABLE @interface GridView : UIView
@end
```

**GridView.m**

```
#import "GridView.h"

enum GRID_BOX_TYPE
{
    GRID_BOX_BLANK = 0,
    GRID_BOX_RED,
    GRID_BOX_BLUE
};

#define NUMBER_OF_ROWS  5
#define NUMBER_OF_COLS  4

#define GRID_LINE_WIDTH 2

@implementation GridView
{
    enum GRID_BOX_TYPE twoDGrid[NUMBER_OF_ROWS][NUMBER_OF_COLS];
    CGSize gridSizeRatio;
}
#pragma mark init methods
-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if(self){
        //do initialization here
        [self commonInitializer];
    }
    return self;
}

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if(self){
        //do initialization here
        [self commonInitializer];
    }
    return self;
}

// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
//    CGContextClearRect(context, rect);
    
    //global settings
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);
    
    
    for(int i=0;i<NUMBER_OF_ROWS;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<NUMBER_OF_COLS;j++)
        {
            enum GRID_BOX_TYPE blockType = twoDGrid[i][j];
            
            switch (blockType) {
                case GRID_BOX_BLANK :
                {
                    //draw white box
                    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);
            
                    CGContextStrokeRectWithWidth(context, CGRectMake(j * rect.size.width * gridSizeRatio.width,
                                                         i * rect.size.height * gridSizeRatio.height,
                                                         rect.size.width * gridSizeRatio.width - GRID_LINE_WIDTH,
                                                         rect.size.height * gridSizeRatio.height - GRID_LINE_WIDTH), GRID_LINE_WIDTH);
                    CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFill);
                }
                    break;
                case GRID_BOX_RED:
                {
                    //draw red box
                    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
                    
                    CGContextStrokeRectWithWidth(context, CGRectMake(j * rect.size.width * gridSizeRatio.width,
                                                         i * rect.size.height * gridSizeRatio.height,
                                                         rect.size.width * gridSizeRatio.width - GRID_LINE_WIDTH,
                                                         rect.size.height * gridSizeRatio.height - GRID_LINE_WIDTH), GRID_LINE_WIDTH);
                    
                    CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFill);
                }
                    break;
                case GRID_BOX_BLUE:
                {
                    //draw blue box
                    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blueColor].CGColor);
                    
                    CGContextStrokeRectWithWidth(context, CGRectMake(j * rect.size.width * gridSizeRatio.width,
                                                         i * rect.size.height * gridSizeRatio.height,
                                                         rect.size.width * gridSizeRatio.width - GRID_LINE_WIDTH,
                                                         rect.size.height * gridSizeRatio.height - GRID_LINE_WIDTH), GRID_LINE_WIDTH);
                    CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFill);
                }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            
            
        }
    }
}

#pragma mark private initializer
-(void)commonInitializer
{
    twoDGrid[0][0]= GRID_BOX_RED;
    twoDGrid[0][1]= GRID_BOX_RED;
    twoDGrid[0][2]= GRID_BOX_RED;
    twoDGrid[0][3]= GRID_BOX_RED;
    twoDGrid[1][0]= GRID_BOX_RED;
    twoDGrid[1][1]= GRID_BOX_BLANK;
    twoDGrid[1][2]= GRID_BOX_BLANK;
    twoDGrid[1][3]= GRID_BOX_RED;
    twoDGrid[2][0]= GRID_BOX_RED;
    twoDGrid[2][1]= GRID_BOX_BLUE;
    twoDGrid[2][2]= GRID_BOX_BLUE;
    twoDGrid[2][3]= GRID_BOX_RED;
    twoDGrid[3][0]= GRID_BOX_RED;
    twoDGrid[3][1]= GRID_BOX_BLANK;
    twoDGrid[3][2]= GRID_BOX_BLANK;
    twoDGrid[3][3]= GRID_BOX_RED;
    twoDGrid[4][0]= GRID_BOX_RED;
    twoDGrid[4][1]= GRID_BOX_RED;
    twoDGrid[4][2]= GRID_BOX_RED;
    twoDGrid[4][3]= GRID_BOX_RED;
    
    gridSizeRatio = CGSizeMake(1.0/NUMBER_OF_COLS, 1.0/NUMBER_OF_ROWS);
}
@end
```

**Preview**

[image]

Comment: Hey Rahul, I got your concept but will please provide me any sample code for same.

Comment: hey, it's Ratul not Rahul :P, btw please mark the answer as accepted, as it meet your requirement :).